# Transposing my array

Tags: java, arrays, transpose

Right now I have an deck of cards that prints out like so:

```
A of ♠    9 of ♥    6 of ♣    J of ♦    9 of ♦    2 of ♣    9 of ♠    
6 of ♦    2 of ♦    Q of ♠    6 of ♠    5 of ♠    J of ♥    7 of ♦    
K of ♣    4 of ♦    8 of ♣    K of ♥    T of ♥    5 of ♣    A of ♦    
7 of ♣    T of ♠    7 of ♥    T of ♣    A of ♣    8 of ♦    7 of ♠    
2 of ♥    K of ♠    8 of ♠    J of ♠    8 of ♥    J of ♣    4 of ♣    
3 of ♦    5 of ♥    Q of ♦    T of ♦    4 of ♥    Q of ♥    3 of ♣    
K of ♦    2 of ♠    3 of ♥    3 of ♠    4 of ♠    9 of ♣    5 of ♦
```

I am want to ask the user what row their card is in, then I want to flip the printed table so that their row is a column.

How do I distinguish the rows so that I can ask the user, and how do I then flip the table so that their row is now a column.

Do I need to transpose this? How would I do that?

```
public class Deck {
    private Card[] deck;
    private int currentCard;
    String[][] multi = new String[7][7];

    public Deck() {
        String[] Faces = {
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"
        };
        String[] Suits = {
            "♠", "♣", "♦", "♥"
        };

        deck = new Card[52];
        currentCard = 0;

        for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
            for (int face = 0; face < 13; face++) {
                deck[(face + (suit * 13))] = new Card(Suits[suit], Faces[face]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        currentCard = 0;

        SecureRandom randomNumber = new SecureRandom();

        for (int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++) {
            int second = randomNumber.nextInt(52);

            Card temp = deck[first];

            deck[first] = deck[second];
            deck[second] = temp;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        int k;
        k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
                System.out.print(deck[k++] + "    ");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return (s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck theDeck = new Deck();
        theDeck.shuffle();
        theDeck.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just swap `multi[i][j]` with `multi[j][i]`.

Comment: @Andy - He's not using multidimensional arrays here.

Comment: @BadZen really? What's this then: `String[][] multi = new String[7][7];`.

Comment: You can invert the `idx = face + (suit*13)` here with `int suit = idx/13` and `int face = idx%13`.   Then swap `face` and `idx` and redo the first expression!

Comment: @AndyTurner   It's an unreferenced variable declaration.  Did you even read the source?

Comment: @BadZen clearly not! It just seemed coincidental that it's a 7x7 array, and OP's output is 7x7.

Comment: @Karavi note that your `toString` method should return the string containing the data, *not* print it out. More often than not, you aren't simply printing the data to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make deck a two dimensional array with the amount of rows and columns you want: `private Card[#rows][#columns] deck;`. Then you have to rewrite your fill, shuffle and toString algorithm, but that is going to save you a lot of time.

When you want to change the rows to columns, you can just change from `deck[row][column]` to `deck[column][row]` like Andy pointed out.

For asking the user you can just check if the value lies between 0 and `deck.length` and again 0 and `deck[0].length`.